# Magento 301 redirects

Tags: magento, url, redirect, sef

Having some issues with Magento URLs. I've been tasked with redirecting the following ugly URLs

/accesories//accesories/bags-purses.html
/accesories//accesories/bags-purses.html/cat/bags-purses

To

/accesories/bags-purses

I can't redirect using Magento's URLs rewrite manager because of the //. It won't except the path.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Also has anyone else faced this issue before? Why were URLs created like this? I've not used Magento before so any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: May be you can try following module : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/optimise-web-s-mass-301-redirects-for-404-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/optimise-web-s-mass-301-redirects-for-404-pages.html)?

If you want to redirect these links but they are still active there is a way to overwrite the above extension section where they check for 404's first. 
You need to override the `Optimiseweb_Redirects_Model_Redirector` model and
change line 40-ish from

```
if (($actionName == 'noRoute') OR $disabledProductCheck OR $disabledCategoryCheck) (Optimise Web 301 Redirect Extenision check for 404)
```

to

```
if (($actionName) OR $disabledProductCheck OR $disabledCategoryCheck) {
```